# Login de um sistema externo usando ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Estou precisando implementar uma forma do meu sistema (escrito em ASP.NET MVC) realizar o login de um sistema externo ao qual não possuo o código-fonte. Esse sistema externo utiliza utiliza os mesmos usuários do meu sistema. Como faço para, ao logar no meu sistema, logue também no outro sistema?

Comment: Deixe eu ver se eu entendi. Você quer que usuário autentique em seu sistema e automaticamente autentique em outro que você não possui acesso aos fontes? É isso que está buscando?

Comment: exatamente. Não posso alterar o sistema externo

Comment: você precisa interagir com ele através de um serviço (uma API, um Webservice...) e esse outro sistema tem que disponibilizar esse serviço para que você possa consumir...

Comment: O sistema externo tem uma tela de login correto?

Comment: -1 por pedir um tutorial.

Comment: @Randrade tecnicamente não existe uma resposta certo? Isso é ilegal? Se um sistema não disponibilizada meios alternativos de autenticação, tentar realizá-la de outra forma não seria ilegal?

Comment: não, o meu sistema precisa se comunicar com um sistema de helpdesk utilizado pelo cliente.

Comment: Sim, o sistema externo possui uma tela de login

Comment: @durtto Ilegal não é, pois ele possui o usuário e senha. Ilegal seria se ele "forçasse" a quebra de senha, ou algo invasivo.

Answer (score 1):

Em resumo, da forma que você descreveu, **não tem como fazer isso.**

São dois sistemas distintos, sem web service ou qualquer tipo de autenticação conjunta, a não ser os mesmos usuários e senhas.

Somente com esses fatores não é possível fazer o que deseja, até mesmo por questão de segurança.

Se existisse um Web Service para autenticação, ou outro mecanismo, como o [OAuth da Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2), isso poderia ser possível.

#### Possível tentativa

Uma tentativa para fazer isso é desenvolver um [Web Crawler](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastreador_web) para preencher os dados digitados em seu sistema (após a autenticação) na tela de login do sistema externo. Porém, isso pode ser relativo no tipo de autenticação utilizado no outro sistema.

Uma outra tentativa é desenvolver uma funcionalidade no sistema externo para receber os dados de autenticação (de preferência criptografados) e realizar a autenticação no outro sistema. Mas isso exigiria a modificação no sistema externo, pois não deve existir essa funcionalidade.

Comment: no caso, bem resumidamente, estou querendo fazer um Sign-Sigle-On

Comment: @GustavoCorreiaSantos Eu entendi. Mas sem acesso ao código do sistema externo, não é possível fazer isso.